# Raspberry Pi couldn't find wireless interfaces!

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, networkmanager

After a while I have started my raspberry pi, the wifi disconnects and when I am clicking on my Wifi icon it is saying 
No wireless interfaces found
How am I supposed to solve this?

Comment: You wrote that you started the RasPi and the wifi disconnects. Was it connected at any time?

Comment: yes before opening the browser. I had to setup raspbian again that sd card to fix that problem